# How to animate item added to the top of flatlist in React Native LayoutAnimation

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to animate my flatlist when a new item at index 0 state using LayoutAnimation as an actuality feed.

I've try to configureNext animation before adding my item to the list, but the animation look on the last item of my flatlist.

```
const Screen = () => {
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

    const addItem = () => {
        LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.easeInEaseOut);
        setItems([{title: "item"}, ...items]);
    }

    return <View>
        <FlatList keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                  data={items}
                  renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.title}</Text>}
        />
        <Button onPress={addItem} title={"Add item"}/>
    </View>
}
```

Here the snack for this solution :
https://snack.expo.io/2fr3PHXht

I've also tryed to use the `inverted` prop of the flatlist, reverse my item array et force scroll to top when item is added. But when there is no enough item to fill the viewport, my item stick at the bottom of my screen.

I would like to learn how to deal with this type of animation.

Answer (score 0):

These took me hours to figure out! I was having the exact same problem, the issue is in the keyExtractor function use this instead:

```
<FlatList keyExtractor={(item, index) => items.length - index}
              data={items}
              renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.title}</Text>}
    />
```